# JQuery Image Swap

Tags: jquery, css

I have 6 images (3 full size and 3 thumbnails) and have loaded each image url into a javascript variable. On my page I have 3 images displaying: one full size and two thumbnails. When the user clicks a thumbnail, I'd like for the full size image to display the full size version of the clicked thumbnail, and the thumbnail to display the thumbnail version of the previous full size image.

I can get this to occur once with the script below. I could also build a giant if/then block to check all cases, but I'm looking for something more elegant. Any ideas?

Thanks!

```
    function add_image_header(){
    global $post;

    $image_header = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'image_header', true );
    $image_one_full = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'image_one_full', true );
    $image_one_cropped = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'image_one_cropped', true );
    $image_two_full = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'image_two_full', true );
    $image_two_cropped = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'image_two_cropped', true );
    $image_three_full = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'image_three_full', true );
    $image_three_cropped = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'image_three_cropped', true );

    $page_meta_desc = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'thesis_description', true );

    if($image_header){
        ?>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#thumb_one").click(function(){
                        var imageOneFull = "<?php echo $image_one_full;?>";
                        var imageOneCropped = "<?php echo $image_one_cropped;?>";
                        var imageTwoFull = "<?php echo $image_two_full;?>";
                        var imageTwoCropped = "<?php echo $image_two_cropped;?>";
                        var imageThreeFull = "<?php echo $image_three_full;?>";
                        var imageThreeCropped = "<?php echo $image_three_cropped;?>";

                        $('#thumb_one').click($('#main_image').attr("src",imageTwoFull));
                        $('#thumb_one').click($('#thumb_one').attr("src",imageOneCropped));
                    });
                });
            </script>

            <div id="img_header_container">
                <img src="<?php echo $image_one_full;?>" id="main_image"/>
                <img src="<?php echo $image_two_cropped;?>" id="thumb_one"/>
                <img src="<?php echo $image_three_cropped;?>" id="thumb_two"/>
                <div id="heading_text"><h2><?php echo get_the_title($ID) ?></h2><?php echo $page_meta_desc;?></div>
            </div>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give you two solutions.

**1) Use all 3 three thumbnails (which I like more)**

HTML:

```
<div id="img_header_container">
            <img src="<?php echo $image_one_full;?>" id="main_image"/>
            <img class="thumb" data-main="?php echo $image_one_full;?>" src="<?php echo $image_one_cropped;?>" />
            <img class="thumb" data-main="?php echo $image_two_full;?>" src="<?php echo $image_two_cropped;?>"/>
            <img class="thumb" data-main="?php echo $image_three_full;?>" src="<?php echo $image_three_cropped;?>"/>
 </div>
```

Jquery:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".thumb").click(function(){
                   $('#main_image').attr("src", $(this).data('main'));
                });
  });
```

**2) Use 2 thumbnails (as requested)**

HTML:

```
<div id="img_header_container">
            <img data-thumb="<?php echo $image_one_cropped;?>" src="<?php echo $image_one_full;?>" id="main_image"/>
            <img class="thumb" data-main="?php echo $image_two_full;?>" src="<?php echo $image_two_cropped;?>"/>
            <img class="thumb" data-main="?php echo $image_three_full;?>" src="<?php echo $image_three_cropped;?>"/>
 </div>
```

Jquery:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".thumb").click(function(){
                   var Image1Main = $(this).data('main');
                   var Image1Thumb = $(this).attr('src');

                   var Image2Main = $('#main_image').attr('src');
                   var Image2Thumb = $('#main_image').data('thumb');

                   $('#main_image').attr("src", Image1Main);
                   $('#main_image').data("thumb", Image1Thumb);


                   $(this).attr("src", Image2Thumb);
                   $(this).data("main", Image2Main);
                });
  });
```

Comment: Yep, that works! Although for anyone else using this don't forget the opening "<" after data-main="

Comment: Thanks! I agree that having all the thumbnails makes more sense, but I'm not the client.

Answer (score 0):

1. Treat each thumbnail the same, adding a thumbnail class to them
2. Add to each thumbnail attributes called thumb_image and main_image (dont know if this is a correct use of html, but it works)
3. When a thubmnail is clicked, swap thumb_image and main_image with the ones from #main_image (using the magic of $(this) ).
4. Set the image to full_size on the main image, and to thumb_image on the thumbnail